# Two ASP.NET sites sharing application files but with different web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, web-config

Is it possible using virtual directories and/or virtual applications to set up two web sites that share the same application code (aspx pages etc.) but have different web.config files?  The sites and code are residing on the same server running on the same IIS.

I am using IIS 6.

Comment: What is the difference between the two .config files? Perhaps just related to authentication and authorization? It's usually possible to find other ways to handle issues like these (like, sharing between the Internet site and the Intranet site that manages it).

Comment: The only difference is some appSettings.  I was just curious to know if I could do this without changing any code.

Comment: @Jakob- You could do it with app settings by prefixing some kind of app specific key, but that would still require a code change.

Comment: @Jakob: ok, now what's the difference between the IIS sites or virtual directories? Is one VD used by one set of users and the other by another set? Are these sets disjoint (no members in common)? If so, then I would change the code (sorry) so that the different appSettings are instead driven from some property of the logged in user. Perhaps the host header used; perhaps a role the user is in. The .config files would be identical, but you'd get these different settings from a database or other config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no if you want to keep the code in one place. Probably the best solution is to have the application loading a custom config file based on what you determine the site to be (presumably host header?).

Something like [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx) may be useful.

I guess an alternative is to come up with a configuration convention where you have everything in the one file and use [GetSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.getsection.aspx) (with some kind of app specific prefix) to get the specific settings for what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I know this can be done in other ways.  I was just hoping I could do it without changing the existing code.

Comment: The short answer is "yes", not using virtual directories though, but NTFS hard-links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889661/several-asp-net-sites-that-are-sharing-application-files-but-using-different-th

Answer (score 2):

I pretty sure I did this once years ago in order to have a different db connection string for each instance of a website. My guess was that there was a virtual directory for each instance of the website which *only* contained a web.config with instance specific settings in and then inside each of these virtual directories was an app which referenced the source code (which included a shared web.config).

Thus the trick, if I remember correctly, was, for a given website, to have a virtual directory which only contained a web.config. The values in this would be inherited by that virtual directory's sub-app.

Comment: Cool. Have you noticed which web.config takes precedence? The inner or the outer? I seem to recall it being the outer.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible.

Why ???

Becuase the asp.net worker process will read the default configuration file from the physical folder where the application is physically residing. Virtual directories have got nothing to do with web.config. It is just used by webserver(IIS) to map to a particular physical directory as root of the website.

Thanks.

Comment: -1 for 'Virtual directories have got nothing to do with web.config.' See here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.100).aspx#configuration_inheritance, 'When the server receives a request for a particular Web resource, ASP.NET computes the configuration settings for that resource hierarchically, using all the configuration files located in the virtual directory path for the requested URL.'

Answer (score 0):

should be, the web.config in the virtual application will be used. If the layout is hierarchical you may need to look out for web.config inheritance

Comment: I should add, you would need 2 physical copies of the application code as a web.config would be needed in each

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have application A, application B, application C and so on, that are all exactly the same, except they differ by some configuration properties as defined in their web.config files.

Of course this is possible - easiest way is to set up the project as a web application, then compile, then share that dll amongst the applications. You can use the GAC is you wish.

You can set up individual sites in IIS that point to the a shared directory (or use a virtual directory in each) where all the logic sits, but you can't share the app_code folder.

EDIT

RichardOD has the best answer above, and I have implemented something similar before. Basically, I set up a custom config file that is references by the web.config (to prevent app restarts when I make changes to it). This file is read by host name, and contains specific properties on a per-host basis.

All I do is add host headers to IIS, and an entry for that host in the custom config file. Done.