# How to setup 1 IIS server, with multiple sites, same code/binaries, different web configs without duplication?

Tags: web-config, connection-string, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there a way to setup multiple sites on 1 Windows IIS server, where each site has the same binaries/code (same functionality), but different web configs, without making duplicate copies of the same code code for each site?

That is, is there a way for, say, 50 sites, each having a different domain, all to "share" the same code and binaries on Windows Server, but each site behaves differently because each site has a different web config that contains different database connection strings?

I don't want to make 50 copies of the same code/binaries in different folders, where the difference in each folder is that it has a different/unique web config file (really, just the database connection string). Maintenance is a nightmare, and it's a waste of HDD space.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to create different sites sharing the same code on IIS. Having multiple IIS applications do this to the same folder on the filesystem introduces complications and errors due to file permissions and access permissions. Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58524811/can-i-share-same-application-files-between-multiple-applications-where-only-web and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001332/two-asp-net-sites-sharing-application-files-but-with-different-web-config

Comment: Thanks @YurongDai. I have 1300 copies of the same code, which is huge waste of space, and a maintenance nightmare. I was able to solve a part of it with the Windows mklink feature (symbolic/junction/hard links), but I don't like that solution.
(this is a fragile, legacy application, written 15 years ago, with over 1300 customers, so modifying the code isn't a palatable option)

Comment: Unless you charge your customers nothing, the payments you received should well cover the HDD space. Don't try to take shortcuts, as that might bite you badly in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "bypass" the problem by using symbolic links. I setup symbolic links - both junctions and hard links - from the single source of binaries, to 1300 folders/ sites. I used PowerShell to automate most of it.

I don't quite like this approach, but it helps me avoid the problem of deploying the same code to 1300 sites - which has been buggy and problematic from the beginning.
With this approach, the only thing I need to place that's different in each site's root folder is the web config.